# Unknotting number formally?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, knot-theory

I am reading Colin C. Adams's very nice but not always rigorous "The Knot Book" right now. How does one formalize the [unknotting number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unknotting_number)? (For example, is some restriction on embeddings $S^1\hookrightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ required besides continuity for unknotting number to exist?) What is a reference for a formal proof that every knot in some category (maybe PL?) has finite unknotting number?

Comment: I believe this should be in Lickorish, *An Introduction to Knot Theory*, but I do not have a copy handy right now.

Comment: @Neal I will check library tomorrow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A (say PL) knot diagram $D$ can be thought of as a (PL) immersed curve in the plane with only transverse double points such that each of the double points carries "crossing information", i.e. it is decorated in a way to depict which strand passes over the other. A crossing change just alters the decoration at one of the double points so that the over and under strands are interchange.

The unknotting number $u(D)$ of a diagram $D$ is the minimum number of crossing changes necessary to change $D$ into a diagram of the unknot. The unknotting number of a diagram is always finite, and here's one way to see that. Let $p$ be some basepoint on the knot away from the crossings. Start traveling along the knot from $p$ (in an arbitrary direction). Perform crossing changes (if necessary) so that the first time you encounter any crossing, you encounter it along an "over" strand. Such a diagram is always the unknot. Suppose that the diagram is in the $(x,y)$-plane, and that direction of projection is the $z$-axis. Then the embedding of the knot in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be taken to be decreasing in the $z$-direction except for one line segment that parallel to the $z$-axis that projects to the point $p$.

The unknotting number $u(K)$ of the knot $K$ is then defined as
$$u(K) = \min\{u(D)~|~D~\text{is a diagram of }K\}.$$
Since each $u(D)$ is finite, of course $u(K)$ is also finite.

Comment: I might add that PL knots have PL diagrams, and PL diagrams have an unknotting number (hence giving an upper bound for the unknotting number of the knot), and furthermore that every finite unknotting of a knot can be realized as a diagram.  Hence the diagram and non-diagram versions of unknotting number are equal.